# Sectioning items with links to their parents

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

Is there any way to have  "sectioning" commands (`\section` `\subsection`, etc) create *automatically* a link with a specified symbol to their parent sectioning item?

Illustration below

[image]

The underlying code for the above

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[66]

\subsection{Foo}
\subsubsection{Smaller 1}
\lipsum[66]

\subsubsection{Smaller 2} 
\lipsum[66]

\subsection{Bar}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that hyperref already provides targets for each section, subsection etc.  The only tricky bit is that `\subsection` (for example) does not actually handle the title, but simply passes it on to `\@startsection`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldsubsection=\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[2][\empty]{% #1 = short tietle (optional), #2 = title
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \oldsubsection[#2]{#2~\hyperlink{section.\thesection}{\faPaperclip}}
  \else
    \oldsubsection[#1]{#2~\hyperlink{section.\thesection}{\faPaperclip}}
  \fi}

\let\oldsubsubsection=\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[2][\empty]{% #1 = short tietle (optional), #2 = title
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \oldsubsubsection[#2]{#2~\hyperlink{subsection.\thesubsection}{\faPaperclip}}
  \else
    \oldsubsubsection[#1]{#2~\hyperlink{subsection.\thesubsection}{\faPaperclip}}
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[66]

\subsection{Foo}
\subsubsection{Smaller 1}
\lipsum[66]

\subsubsection{Smaller 2} 
\lipsum[66]

\subsection{Bar}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: please [letltxmacro](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro).

Comment: @touhami This should work reliably even without `letltxmacro` AFAIK, because `\subsection` and  `\subsubsection` take no argument (in `article.cls` at the very least).

Comment: OK. sorry i was mistaken. I was about a problem in redefining `\...section` this way, these is because of  using `\@dblarg`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. TeX is Turing complete.

OK, now how to go about doing this? I don't think there's any pre-packaged way to do this so you'd have to do a bit of programming work. My approach would be to have each section automatically generate a anchor for itself (probably based on the section number) and store this in a macro that gets redefined with each section. Then, assuming you're using the hyperref package, you could define your subsections to include at the end of the subsection title, something like `\hyperref[\currentsectionlink]{⤴️}`. Details are left as an exercise to the reader.